# Elastic API doesn't show all documents

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, fetch

i have elastic that i want to fetch the data from elastic with query, i have about 210 documents in the index, but when i tried to search with query match_all, the api only showing 7 documents and not all documents, is it possible to api showing all documents instead only show some documents.

The query :

```
192.168.20.47:9200/new/_search
{
 "query" : {
  "match_all" : {}
 }
}
```

The elastic API result :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 210,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Gani Kartiwa Adiwisastra",
          "nip" : "123",
          "pnid" : "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "BT",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "26/11/2015",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Director",
            "sector" : "Direksi",
            "department" : "Direksi",
            "division" : "Management",
            "superior" : "Director"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c8ffe9a587b126f152ed3d89a146b445",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Firmansyah",
          "nip" : "124",
          "pnid" : "9996535e07258a7bbfd8b132435c5962",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "BT",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "BE Programmer",
            "sector" : "MAI",
            "department" : "MAI",
            "division" : "MAI",
            "superior" : "Be Programmer"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "069059b7ef840f0c74a814ec9237b6ec",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Erna Tri Rahayu",
          "nip" : "126",
          "pnid" : "a9eb812238f753132652ae09963a05e9",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "Sudirman",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Finance Officer",
            "sector" : "Finance & Accounting",
            "department" : "Finance & Accounting",
            "division" : "Finance & Accounting",
            "superior" : "Finance Officer"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ec5decca5ed3d6b8079e2e7e7bacc9f2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sukidi",
          "nip" : "127",
          "pnid" : "d38901788c533e8286cb6400b40b386d",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "Sudirman",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "OB",
            "sector" : "GA",
            "department" : "HR & GA",
            "division" : "HR & GA",
            "superior" : "Ob"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "76dc611d6ebaafc66cc0879c71b5db5c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Ni Nyoman Indah Suwardani",
          "nip" : "128",
          "pnid" : "b3ba8f1bee1238a2f37603d90b58898d",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "Sudirman",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "22/09/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Account  Manager",
            "sector" : "S&M Project",
            "department" : "S&M Project",
            "division" : "Sales & Marketing",
            "superior" : "Account  Manager"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "d1f491a404d6854880943e5c3cd9ca25",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sendhy Ferdiyanto",
          "nip" : "129",
          "pnid" : "a9078e8653368c9c291ae2f8b74012e7",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "BT",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Project Support",
            "sector" : "Project Support",
            "department" : "S&M Project",
            "division" : "Sales & Marketing",
            "superior" : "Project Support"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9b8619251a19057cff70779273e95aa6",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Hendra Pratama",
          "nip" : "130",
          "pnid" : "1c65cef3dfd1e00c0b03923a1c591db4",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "BT",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Project Support",
            "sector" : "Project Support",
            "department" : "S&M Project",
            "division" : "Sales & Marketing",
            "superior" : "Project Support"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1afa34a7f984eeabdbb0a7d494132ee5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Detty Ayu",
          "nip" : "131",
          "pnid" : "2de5d16682c3c35007e4e92982f1a2ba",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "Sudirman",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "13/01/2015",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Corporate Secretary",
            "sector" : "PA / Sekretaris",
            "department" : "PA / Sekretaris",
            "division" : "Managemen",
            "superior" : "Corporate Secretary"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "65ded5353c5ee48d0b7d48c591b8f430",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Deri Alvian",
          "nip" : "132",
          "pnid" : "e1d5be1c7f2f456670de3d53c7b54f4a",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "BT",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "21/01/2014",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Project Support",
            "sector" : "Project Support",
            "department" : "S&M Project",
            "division" : "Sales & Marketing",
            "superior" : "Project Support"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "em-employeedata",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9fc3d7152ba9336a670e36d0ed79bc43",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Netty Purwanti",
          "nip" : "133",
          "pnid" : "2c89109d42178de8a367c0228f169bf8",
          "companycode" : "EBT",
          "worklocationcode" : "Sudirman",
          "employee" : {
            "start" : "04/05/2015",
            "end" : "29/05/1453",
            "status" : "P"
          },
          "organization" : {
            "position" : "Account Executive Central Government",
            "sector" : "S&M Central Government",
            "department" : "S&M Central Government",
            "division" : "Sales & Marketing",
            "superior" : "Account Executive Central Government"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 10 results (not 7). This is because you didn't specify a `size`.

From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/paginate-search-results.html):

> By default, searches return the top 10 matching hits. To page through a larger set of results, you can use the search API's `from` and `size` parameters. The `from` parameter defines the number of hits to skip, defaulting to 0. The `size` parameter is the maximum number of hits to return. Together, these two parameters define a page of results.

So, this is how your query would look with the maximum `size` of 10,000:

```
192.168.20.47:9200/new/_search
{
 "query" : {
  "match_all" : {}
 },
 "size" : 10000
}
```

Comment: GET em-employeedata/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}